# How to iterate over the rows

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy

I want to iterate over the column "Name" which should have only "ROSE" and the next column should be "Fail" and should extract the column "places" corresponding to the FAIL and ROSE.

[INPUT](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Voxws.png)

Output :

[OUTPUT](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9c8rz.png)

Comment: [How to make good reproducible pandas examples](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples)

Comment: `df.query("Name=='Rose' and Condition=='Fail'")`

Comment: @AnuragDabas I need to fecth the corresponding places as well

Comment: @TajinderSingh This is a different scenario.

Comment: what do you mean by *'I need to fetch the corresponding places as well'*?

Comment: @AnuragDabas in this example I have to fetch only INDIA and USA.  The name is ROSE and the condition is FALSE so I have to fetch the corresponding place. Pls look into the output snapshot once

Comment: try: `cond=(df['Name']=='Rose') & (df['Condition']=='Fail') & df['Place'].isin(['USA','India'])` finally `df[cond]` or `df.loc[cond]`

Comment: @AnuragDabas It can be anything X, Y , Z .. Not just USA , INDIA. based on the condition of column "Condition as FAIL" the corresponding value from the place column has be to fetched

Comment: have a look on the previous comment and read this line *I have to fetch only INDIA and USA*

Comment: @AnuragDabas The values in column "Place" is not constant.. It keeps changing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
df[(df["Name"] == "Rose") & (df["Condition"] == "Fail")]
```

Output

```
   Name   Status  Place
0  Rose     Fail  India
1  Rose     Fail    USA
2  Rose     Fail      X
```

To fetch only Place column as a list

```
df[(df["Name"] == "Rose") & (df["Condition"] == "Fail")]["Place"].tolist()
```

Output

```
   ['India', 'USA', 'X']
```

Comment: The corresponding Places also has to be fetched

Comment: Do you mean, you would like to have as output a list [India, USA] ?

Comment: Based on the condition of ROSE , FAIL ... its corresponding value in the same row in the place column has to be fetched. It can be anything .. x,y.. not just india , usa..

Comment: The code above returns the PLACE column values (which can be anything not just india or usa) for the rows satisfying the (Rose and Fail) condition.

Comment: Please accept my answer if it answered your question (https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Comment: Hey what if I am getting the Name column from the user. "Rose" should be from user input. all other things are same. @YuserT

Comment: A code snippet of how you are getting the Name column from the user would be useful.